# download an excel file from php which have different array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, excel

I want to write different arrays from my php script to different rows of an excel file. I know there are many ways to do that.

I got a small script which downloads an excel file but not supporting my array to insert into the content.. please help me,if it need any changes.

Thanks

```
    $shop['id']=$column['id'];
    $shop['name']=$column['name'];
    $shop['cat1'] = $cat1;
    $shop['cat2'] = $cat2;
    $shop['cat3'] = $cat3;
    $all_shops[$column['id']] = $shop; 



$filename ="cat.xls";
$contents = "$shop['cat2']";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to stream th content as HTML in output.
(Ex : change extension .html to .xls, it will open smoothly in Excel)

```
$shop['id']=$column['id'];
$shop['name']=$column['name'];
$shop['cat1'] = $cat1;
$shop['cat2'] = $cat2;
$shop['cat3'] = $cat3;
$all_shops[$column['id']] = $shop; 

$content = "<table>";
foreach($all_shops as $k => $shop){
   $content .= "<tr><td>ID</td><td>{$shop['id']}</td></tr>"; // add other columns
}
$content .= "</table>";

$filename ="cat.xls";
$contents = "$shop['cat2']";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: Smoothly? Except that the most recent versions of Excel will give you a warning that the file format doesn't match the file extension - guess it depends on your definition of "smooth"